# Create variable from constant

Tags: php

I want to ommit creating countless `if/else` statements and use predefined variables (or constants) instead.

```
DEFINE('LANG',$current_lang);
```

It returns either `pl` or `en`. And now I have two variables:

```
$pl = getid('o-nas');
$en = pll_get_post($pl, 'en');
```

How can I print the one I defined earlier with `LANG`? Or is there a better solution for that? Please note that I will have multiple cases of such things, but the `LANG` will always be either one of those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *variable variable syntax* for this case is:

```
define('FOO', 'bar');

$foo = 'baz';
$bar = 42;

echo ${FOO}; // 42
```

Note that this is not necessarily the best approach to i18n, but it answers your direct question.
A first step at improving this may simply be to use arrays for starters:

```
$content = [
    'en' => ..,
    'pl' => ..
];
echo $content[LANG];
```

The intent and syntax here is much more obvious and readable.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen that before ;-) Thanks alot, it will save me a lot of trouble! (actually I've seen it at the manual, but didn't quite understand, until now, so double-thanks!)

Comment: I know it's not the best approach to `i18n`, but I use WordPress' `get_post` function, so I'm interested in getting the `id` of the page and then displaying the right one.